# How to get the same ratio of plot and the picture in R?

Tags: r, image, plot, scatter-plot

I have 2D landmarks data (x,y) of bones and I plot it using the function `plot` in R language.

The problems:

1. Since the x-axis and y-axis have the same unit, I want the plot to have an actual size.

[When I save as a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CP2L.png)

[The picture that I want (manual adjusted in RStudio)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFRfJ.png)

The length between 150 and 350 on the x-axis must be half the length between 100 and 500 in the picture.

```
png("picture.png") 
plot(data)   
dev.off()
```

This is the code that I use to save the picture on my computer.

Comment: Set `asp = 1` in your `plot` command to set the aspect ratio to 1.

Comment: You may also want to use the `height` and `width` arguments of `png()` to set a an appropriate size. See the `?png` help page for examples.